# Counting unique intersecting sets from a list

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a 2 dimensional list of numbers both dimensions of varying length. These represent open ports for hosts. Below is a list showing the open ports on 4 different hosts:

```
ports = [[22,23],[22],[22,23,80],[23,80]]
```

I would like to count all the unique combinations of ports shared by two or more hosts, in this example I should get the following result:

```
Ports -> Count
22     -> 3
22, 23 -> 2
23     -> 3
23, 80 -> 2
80     -> 2
```

I have implemented a solution, but my results are not correct as my counts for a given combination tend to exceed the number of hosts I'm using, for brevity I'm not posting my very long solution, but will outline it in pseudo code:

- Create A Matrix of Intersections between each host
- Extract/flatten the matrix to include only unique sets, ie not the reverse order.

  ```
  -- a AND b, b AND a => a AND b
  ```
- Create a new list containing each unique set of ports from the (extract/flatten) list
  and the number of times that set occurred.

Comment: Why is '[22,23,80]' missing from the outputs. Also, I think it might be better if you did post the relevant parts of your code

Comment: @Dhara count all the unique combinations of ports shared by *two or more hosts*. That's my `[22,23,80]` is missing I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `powerset` recipe from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def port_table(ports):
    d = Counter()
    for portseq in ports:
        for subset in powerset(sorted(portseq)):
            if subset:
                d[subset] += 1
    return d
```

Basically, `powerset` gives all the possible subsets to be incremented (including the empty one, hence the `if subset:` to skip it), and then for each subset we see in each list of ports, we increment a `Counter` object.  This then produces

```
>>> ports = [[22,23],[22],[22,23,80],[23,80]]
>>> table = port_table(ports)
>>> for port, count in sorted(table.items()):
...     if count > 1:
...         print port, '->', count
... 
(22,) -> 3
(22, 23) -> 2
(23,) -> 3
(23, 80) -> 2
(80,) -> 2
```

Comment: I don't see an advantage of using `Counter` here. Just using `defaultdict(int)` will work just as well and keep compatible with 2.5+, but yeah, def. nice use of the itertools recipe!

Comment: @JonClements: it has a better name.  [This would be a stronger argument if I'd given the variable a more descriptive name than "d", of course..]

Comment: Works great, although I do have to limit the size of the ports list. As soon as it gets to large set 25+ ports the memory requirements go through the roof (working with 50 000+ hosts). But that's a hardware problem. Thanks for a elegant solution.

Comment: @Trowalts: two possibilities which come to mind to handle large-scale cases are (1) to decide that you only care about combinations of a certain size (say up to 3 or 4), and (2) to work probabilistically -- `random.shuffle` your list and then only work with a fraction of it.  I've found these useful in the past.